# How do I say "Congratulations, your photo was also seen on XYZ site!" in different ways?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

Is it possible to say "Congratulations, your photo was also seen on XYZ site!" in different ways?

Let say A's photo is listed on "Flickr's Explore" page or A's photo got selected in "Editor's Choice" category and A happened to post the same photo on Facebook too.

How should I post a short and sweet Facebook comment on A's achievement? I need different ways so that I do not sound robotic or repetitive if I need to congratulate on A's next/future photos.

Comment: One option that comes to mind is "your photo was also *featured* on Flickr!", but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: "Congratulations, you're on XYZ too!" seems nice and to the point. You don't want to sound like a marketing e-mail.

Comment: (@Mark, Chenmunka, FumbleFingers, Em1, CollenV) - I asked the above question keeping in my mind about the rule "Word choice and usage" that leads to a either a completely different sentence or different words placement. I (cannot)am not able to edit/reword my question to fit the rules as per the help center. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by the request of the question, i see you need a informal comment. When you are saying something informal you don't need a special way. I would say, *just speak what's on your mind* . Some of examples are below(these may look a little formal)

> Your pic is on Flickr/website name too.
>
> I was happy to find that your photo is featured on Flickr too.
>
> You got famous on Facebook and Flickr.

And even writing *Great pic on Flickr too* would look good. Writing small things like *thanks* never looks like repetitive or *robotic* .

Comment: I'm happy to *have* found (...).

Comment: You will sound robotic and repetitive if you persist in wasting messages on such banal "news", no matter how you word them. If there is a "like" button on the site, that will suffice.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock You are right that would be even a better option!